# How do I detect database name using MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

I am rather new to the PDO library, so I apologize for my inexperience. I am writing a class that uses the PDO library to build and execute queries and return the results, no matter what they are.

Within the class, I detect whether there is an open connection to a database, and if it is the same as the one being configured, it uses this one instead. This is really easy to do using the MsSQL library as the `PDO::getAttribute()` function returns 'CurrentDatabase' and 'SQLServerName', so I can just apply a condition like so:

```
if(!empty($this->PDO)){
    // Get the current connection information
    $current_connection = $this->PDO->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO);
    // Return if the connection is the same
    if($this->connection_parameters['hostname']==$current_connection['SQLServerName']&&$this->connection_parameters['database']==$current_connection['CurrentDatabase']){
        return;
    }
}
```

However, when it comes to MySQL, the data returned from `PDO::getAttribute` is completely different and I cannot seem to get the database name from the current connection.

Does any body know a function or method to get the currently connected database of a MySQL connection using the `PDO` library in `PHP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I order to connect to both MySQL and MsSQL, you must have 2 connections. However, changing the database on a live connection is very simple.

The following simply checks if a PDO instance already exists and whether or not it is using the required database. If so then it continues with this connection, if not it changes the database.

```
// Test if the PDO object already exists
if(!empty($this->PDO)){

    // If connection is the same then select the database
    if($this->connection_engine==$this->PDO->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME)){

        // Get the current database in use
        $database = $this->PDO->query("SELECT {$this->select_db_function}");
        $database = $database->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $database = $database[0][0];

        // If the current database matches the new database then return
        if($database==$this->connection_parameters['database']){
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no point in looking for the opened connection and - especially - in checking for the current database.

Why can't you just open the connection, select the database for it and then use this connection all the time throughout your class - just like everyone does?

Comment: If you execute two queries in one script that uses two different servers, you have to have two connections!

Comment: All right, have 2 instances of the class, what's the problem? Aren't you going to reconnect every time you need another server, are you?

Comment: I will have two instances of the class for two separate connections of course! However, it is slightly confusing with PDO as when you initiate an instance of the class, you have to input a database parameter. I therefore thought that you were not able to change the database without creating a new instance! Thank you for pointing that out, this is obviously the solution then.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting, but the answer was slightly more specific to my needs and I therefore answered it myself. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I don't care for these marks, but I see no point in changing the database this way. if you need to work with 2 databases, you may either create 2 instances or set database in the query, or just use "use database" query without checking or store current database in a variable. Your approach seems worst of them

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing! I am selecting a new database if the database in use is not the same as the required one. If the driver is different then it creates a new instance. I just have not posted all of my code!

Answer (score -1):

See comments on the MySQL manual page for '[USE database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would prefer to do it without using a query. I will use this method as a last resort